# How to share constants between controller and model Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to share constants between controller and model?

e.g. in `product.rb` I have

```
PRODUCT_TYPES = %w[one two]
```

I want `PRODUCT_TYPES` constant to be available in the controllers as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deeply explained the various possibility [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20772813/123527)

You basically have 3 possibilities:

- global scope (initializer)
- application scope (using the application module created by Rails)
- class scope (defined them where you want, and call them with `Class::CONSTANT`)

Answer (score 9):

As per my consideration  your **Product** model  looks like

```
 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
      PRODUCT_TYPES = %w[one two]
 end
```

You can access the given constant in the controller as below

```
p.product_type == Product::PRODUCT_TYPES[:one]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can access model constant in Controller as bellow...

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
       STATUS_PAYABLE          = %w(APPROVED OPEN)
 end

Controller use like ..

 Invoice::STATUS_PAYABLE.include?('OPEN')
```