# Rails 4 constants - 'Unitialized constant' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, constants

I'm attempting to use global constants in a Rails 4 app to validate certain elements, such as emails, ethnic groups, etc. I've followed the approach outlined at the stack overflow article ["How do you store custom constants in Rails 4"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771822/how-do-you-store-custom-constants-in-rails-4), without success.

I've defined a file `lib/constants.rb` as the location for all application-wide constants. In my `config/application.rb` file I've included the following code:

```
module Foo
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # extraneous code omitted 

    config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib') # added this line to include lib directory
  end
end
```

I've tried a couple of options for defining and loading the constants, but I'm still getting errors.

Attempt 1: created a file `lib/constants.rb` with code defining a constant:

```
ETHNIC_GROUPS = ["N/A", "African American/Black", "American Indian", "Hispanic", "Puerto Rican",
      "Alaskan Native", "Asian American/Pacific Islander", "Mexican American/Chicano"]
```

Attempt 2: Based on discussion at article ["Auto-loading lib files in Rails 4"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098663/auto-loading-lib-files-in-rails-4) I modified the filename and code a bit to try and load the constants another way. Per that article I've defined a file `lib/Foo.rb`(matches the application name in `config/application.rb`):

```
module Foo
  # Define custom constants for the application
  ETHNIC_GROUPS = ["N/A", "African American/Black", "American Indian", "Hispanic", "Puerto Rican",
      "Alaskan Native", "Asian American/Pacific Islander", "Mexican American/Chicano"]
end
```

This looks like it would essentially monkey patch, or add to the existing Foo module defined in `config/application.rb` - my assumption, anyway.

I've restarted the server, reloaded the console, etc after each change. No matter how many times I do so, I continue to get the uninitialized constant error. In the console, I've attempted to call both `ETHNIC_GROUPS` and `Foo::ETHNIC_GROUPS` without success.

Appreciate any insight on best practices for working with global application constants in Rails 4, as well as insight into why this isn't working for me.

Comment: You could stick it in config/initializers...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you "**rails_config**" gem: [Github](https://github.com/railsconfig/rails_config)

It allows you to put any number of settings in an .yml file. It also allows to create different settings files for each environment.

Answer (score 1):

A common method would be to create a `common_constant.rb` file in `config/initializers` and add your constants there like

```
module CommonConstants
  MY_VARIABLE = 'foo'
  MY_HASH = {
    foo: 'more foo',
    bar: 'big bar'
  }
  MY_ARRAY = ['foo','bar']
end
```

and to access it

```
CommonConstants::MY_VARIABLE
```

Comment: Thanks @Ojash! Very helpful. See my post below as the answer. Your post got me to try renaming the module in my `lib` directory and it worked. I prefer using `lib` instead of `config/initializers` for storing the file, which is why I decided to post another answer. Your method works, though. I'm not sure what the Rails convention is - seem to have seen discussions that support both methods.

Answer (score 1):

Appreciate the answers! I realized that the issue was defining my module in `lib/Foo.rb` to try and match the application module defined in `config/application.rb`. I would expect that to work, but what did work is:

1. Defined a AppConstants module in `lib/app_constants.rb`:

   ```
   module AppConstants
    ETHNIC_GROUPS = ["N/A", "African American/Black", "American Indian", "Hispanic", "Puerto Rican",
    "Alaskan Native", "Asian American/Pacific Islander", "Mexican American/Chicano"]
   end
   ```
2. Called the constant with `AppConstants::ETHNIC_GROUPS` in the code.

With the (previously defined) code in application.rb to autoload the `lib` directory, this got pulled into the application correctly.

The same result could have been achieved with either the 'rails_config' gem, or with using a `config/initializers/common_constants.rb` file as suggested by @Ojash.

In the end I decided I prefer having the constants in a distinct file within the `lib` directory. This seems a bit cleaner to me. I decided I'd rather not pull in another gem with code I don't necessarily understand.

I don't know why the constant wasn't getting referenced when calling `Foo::ETHNIC_GROUPS` as noted in Option 2 in my original post. The discussion in the article about Auto-loading lib files in Rails 4 seemed to recommend using a lib module with the same name as the application module. After I tried renaming the module it worked.